# change row values to column values in access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I currently have row values with duplicates that was able to change in column values, but i want my column names to be `dependency1`, `dependency2`, `dependency3`, etc.

Currently my results are :

```
idea_code   Network Products    Telehealth  Test1 Test23

I0000555    Network Products            
I0000556                         Telehealth Test1   Test23
```

But I want my columns to look like

```
Idea_Code    Dependency1       dependency2    dependency3 ----
I0000555     Network Products           
I0000556     Telehealth        Test1          Test23
```

My current access query is :

```
TRANSFORM First(DA.dependency_name) AS dependency_name

SELECT DA.idea_code

FROM tbl_IdeasDependencies AS DA

GROUP BY DA.idea_code

PIVOT DA.dependency_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following solution involving a group by query with a derived table subquery. Using a `DependencyCount` by `idea_code`, the main query is transposed with conditional `IIF()` for the numbered Dependency fields:

```
SELECT idea_code, 
       Max(IIF(DependencyCount = 1, dependency_name, "")) As Dependency1,
       Max(IIF(DependencyCount = 2, dependency_name, "")) As Dependency2,
       Max(IIF(DependencyCount = 3, dependency_name, "")) As Dependency3
       ...
FROM
    (
      SELECT  t1.idea_code,         
              t1.dependency_name,
              (SELECT Count(*) 
               FROM tbl_IdeasDependencies t2 
               WHERE t1.idea_code = t2.idea_code 
               AND t1.dependency_name >= t2.dependency_name) As DependencyCount
      FROM tbl_IdeasDependencies t1
)
GROUP BY idea_code
```

Output

```
idea_code   Dependency1         Dependency2     Dependency3
I0000555    Network Products        
I0000556    Telehealth          Test1           Test23
```

Do note with this solution, `dependency_name` values are ordered alphabetically across columns per `idea_code`.

Comment: Thanks Parfait; what happens if I have more than 3 dependencies? I have one to many relationship, so one Idea could have "Many" dependencies. Also I may have confused you with my question,  my current situation is as follows : I have two columns "Idea_Code", "Dependency_Name"  so one idea code could have many dependency name. In order to kill duplication i need to show dependency names as columns which could be one to many relationships, Thanks for your time on it.

Comment: See edit. Since your original table is similar to the union query, you do not need a stage 1. As for the potential many dependency names, you will still need to know in advance the max count for any `idea_code` which will determine the Dependency columns. From there you repeat the `Max(IIF(...` lines in outer main query. See ellipsis `...` above.

Comment: Ideally, you would not need to explicitly create Dependency1-20 columns but MS Access Jet/ACE does not have a native pivot/transpose functionality (different from crosstab). Also unlike rows, column changes in tables are structural changes and hence require explicit column by column referencing (much like naming fields in select clause of SQL queries).